# I am confused with the def of derivative.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The problem given :

Let $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $F:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be differentiable and satisfy $F(x,f(x))=0$ and $\displaystyle \frac {dF}{dy}$ is not zero.
Prove that $f'(x)= -\dfrac {dF}{dx}/\frac {dF}{dy}$ where $y=f(x)$

I am so confused here.

Since $F(x,f(x))=0$, I think, $\displaystyle \frac {dF}{dx}$ must be $0$.

But when I see the $f'(x)$, it seems not.

Is there any difference between $\displaystyle \frac {dF(x,f(x))}{dx}$ and $\displaystyle \left.\frac {dF}{dx} \right|_{(x,f(x))}$  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $f(x) = y$, note that by the chain rule:

$$0 = \frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$$

The result you want follows immediately from this observation.

---

So to recap:

You are correct in supposing that $dF / dx = 0$.  This only works because we are taking the total derivative: it emphatically *does not* mean that $\partial F / \partial x = 0$.

Comment: Wow! It was very helpful. Thanks you very much!

Comment: So, intuitively, is $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ but *without* respect to $f$?